# Regex does not match $ in character set

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm currently fighting a weird javascript regex problem. I'm trying to match all characters between `/` or the end of input. For example this string

```
admin/item/get
```

should be matched as:

```
[ 'admin', 'item', 'get' ]
```

I don't really care if `/` is part of the match or not, so this result would work for me too:

```
[ 'admin/', 'item/', 'get' ]
```

To match the input string `s` I'm using the regex

```
s.match(/.+?[\/$]/g)
```

which results in

```
[ 'admin/', 'item/' ]
```

To my understanding the end of input `$` is not matched in this character set.

When I try to match only the end of input using the regex `s.match(/.+?$/g)` I'm getting the expected result `[ 'admin/item/get' ]`. But placing the `$` in a character set `s.match(/.+?$/g)` the match call returns `null`.

Any help appreciated...

Btw: I'm using node.js 0.8.20

Comment: Why don't you use `split("/")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `$` is treated as a character when placed inside a character set. This should do it though, it uses an alternation inside a non-memory capturing group and thus restores the meaning of `$` to be the end-of-subject:

```
s.match(/.+?(?:\/|$)/g)

["admin/", "bla/", "bla"]
```

As mentioned in the comments:

```
s.split('/')

["admin", "bla", "bla"]
```

Comment: Split is not an option since the question above was somehow lowered in complexity to focus on the $ problem.

Comment: @Saintedlama I understand. Does this solve your issue though?

Answer (score 1):

`$` within character class `[]` has no special meaning and is treated as literal character

It should be

```
.*?(?=\/|$)
```

---

You can instead do this..you dont have to check for `/` or `$`

```
[^/]*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attain the result using regex or split method for string object.

```
var s = "admin/item/get";
```

**Using split method of string object.**

Split the string by `"/"`.

```
s.split("/");

["admin", "item", "get"]
```

**Using regex pattern.**

Match the string with regular expression `/[^\/]+/g`, which matches all characters with occurence of one or more times except `"/"` character.

```
s.match(/[^\/]+/g)

["admin", "item", "get"]
```